# Icons of Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Portuguese are similar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, portuguese-stackoverflow

The icons of [*Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [*Stack Overflow Portugues*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) are the same.

When I earn rep I can't differ where I earned the rep. Is that a problem?

[image: Reputation history]

Above I earned the association bonus on PTSO.

Comment: Title should be be fixed a bit ;)

Comment: May be [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/hola-mundo-cedilla.png) should be used. (Taken from [this blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/ola-mundo-announcing-stack-overflow-in-portuguese/))

Comment: I had the same confusion on the real-time tab on SE. On occasion I've wanted to go in and close the foreign language SO post, only to discover it was simply Portuguese.

Comment: Totally confusing & not good at all :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Icons in PTSO have been modified:

[image: PTSO]